# How do I intercept requests of static resources marked by <mvc:resource/> tag in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Main xml tags:

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/pages/"/>

   <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <bean class="dan.MyInterceptor">
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

All the requests from /pages/** won't enter the interceptor,'/pages/test.jsp',for example.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your webapp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the mvc:mapping tag.  It's redundant, by default an interceptor is run against all requests unless otherwise restricted.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298892/spring-3-mvcresources-causing-mvcinterceptors-to-run-multiple-times) suggests that ordering may be important; try placing the interceptor ahead of the resource mappings.