# Combine mvc:interceptors & mvc:resources to cache only static resources

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure Spring MVC to have the following scheme :

- any url starting with "{context}/resources" should be cacheable
- any other url should not be cacheable (in my case, everything by "resources" are dynamic pages )

The first part is pretty easy using mvc:resource :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="..." cache-period="3600"/>
```

I'm kinda lost for the second part. 
By default, it seems like the "dynamic resources" have no cache-related info (no cache-control header, no pragma, etc...). Some browsers might cache things (FF), some might not (Chrome), which is understanable.

There are many posts about how one can use a combinason of  and WebContentInterceptor to make some pages cacheable :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/foobar/**"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

However in my case this is not useable as such, since I don't have a path expression to match (exclusion is notoriously impossible).

So is there a way I can express this : 
* do what mvc:resources do for resources
* do "something" for all other pages ?

The only alternative I can see would be to write a custom Interceptor which would check whether somehing is a resource, but that sounds a bit strange not to be able to define cache properties globally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC behaves just the way you want it. The *WebContentInterceptor* intercepts and adds cache-control only to the requests for *text/html* resources.

The way to do it for all urls is to leave *<mvc:mapping>* out of the configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Also, because *<mvc:interceptors>* & *<mvc:resources>* are independent, any particular order of those two tags is not important (unlike suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586880/how-do-i-intercept-requests-of-static-resources-marked-by-mvcresource-tag-in)).